# Division by 0 error and CASE - SQL

Tags: sql, division

I am trying to run the query below and keep getting a division by 0 error. There are times that the average in the divisor can be 0. The same query works if I use a HAVING statement where the average is > 0. However, then those valid values are excluded from the results.

```
SELECT B.facility_desc Well,
B.facility_id   "Facility ID",
( Cast(C.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) ),
( Avg(DISTINCT( Cast(A.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) )) ),
( ( Avg(DISTINCT( Cast(A.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) )) ) - ( Cast(C.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) ) ),
CASE
WHEN ( Avg(DISTINCT( Cast(A.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) )) ) = 0 THEN NULL
ELSE (( ( Avg(DISTINCT( Cast(A.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) )) ) - ( Cast(C.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) ) ) / ( Avg(DISTINCT( Cast(A.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) )) ) )
END,
D.desc
FROM   houston_vhs.historicalvalues A
LEFT JOIN houston_fac.fac_header B
ON LEFT(A.pointidlong, 10) = B.facility_id
LEFT JOIN houston_uis.realtimevalues C
ON LEFT(A.pointidlong, 10) = C.facilityid
LEFT JOIN houston_trs.table_header_record D
ON B.facility_table5 = D.table_entry
WHERE  A.pointidlong LIKE 'DIMO_N8%_VGY'
AND A.pointtime > Now() - 7
AND A.unreliableflag = 'N'
AND B.facility_desc <> ''
AND B.facility_is_active = 'Y'
AND C.udc = 'RGAS'
AND C.value <> ''
GROUP  BY B.facility_desc,
B.facility_id,
C.value,
D.desc
ORDER  BY ( ( Avg(DISTINCT( Cast(A.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) )) ) - ( Cast(C.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) ) ) ASC
```

I have tried changing the order of the CASE statement as well to values > 0 then the equation if not then NULL to no avail. I have also tried using NULLIF, it is also a no go. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit of verbose query that would need quite some cognitive effort to parse and understand. It would really increase your chance of getting an answer if  you give a) sample data sets/outputs and/or b) table creation scripts so people can run this query themselves and suggest you options.

Answer (score 0):

In general, SQL evaluates `CASE` expression sequentially.  However, in the presence of aggregation functions, this rule becomes much blurrier -- because the aggregation expressions need to be evaluated first.

A simple fix is to use `nullif()`:

```
 (( ( Avg(DISTINCT( Cast(A.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) )) ) - ( Cast(C.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) ) ) / nullif( Avg(DISTINCT( Cast(A.value AS NUMERIC(6, 0)) )) ), 0 )
```

I want to point out:  I have used SQL for many years (multiple decades) and I have never had reason to use `AVG(DISTINCT)`.  This suggests that your `JOIN`s are duplicating data, and this fix is not the correct fix.